# C++ increment operator

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct, operator-overloading

How to differentiate between overloading the 2 versions of operator ++ ?

```
const T& operator ++(const T& rhs)
```

which one?

```
i++;
++i;
```

Comment: what does your C++ text book have to say on the subject?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These operators are unary, i.e., they do not take a right hand side parameter.

As for your question, if you really must overload these operators, for the preincrement use the signature `const T& operator ++()`, and for the postincrement, `const T& operator(int)`. The int parameter is a dummy.

Comment: They can be non-member functions.

Comment: @gf True. But that wouldn't be my first choice for increment operators. (My first choice would be to not overload operators, anyway.)

Comment: @Daniel: You have no choice if you want to write a C++'ish iterator or iterator-alike object.

Comment: @Zan: ... unless you use boost.iterator to help you with that ;)

Comment: @Zan, that's new to me. Why would you need a nonmember if you want to add `op++` to your iterator?

Comment: @Johannes: I didn't say anything about needing a member or nonmember operator. I just said that you need to overload increment operators to make iterators.

Comment: @Zan ah then i misunderstood your statement to apply to the first part of his comment. Never mentioned :)

Answer (score 11):

For the non-member versions, a function with one parameter is prefix while a function with two parameters and the second being `int` is postfix:

```
struct X {};
X& operator++(X&);      // prefix
X  operator++(X&, int); // postfix
```

For the member-versions, the zero-parameter version is prefix and the one-parameter version taking `int` is postfix:

```
struct X {
    X& operator++();    // prefix
    X  operator++(int); // postfix
};
```

The `int` parameter to calls of the postfix operators will have value zero.

Comment: @gf add an example and this would be the best answer

Answer (score 3):

for the postfix ++ and -- operators, the function must take a dummy `int` argument. if it has no argument, then it's the prefix operator

Answer (score 2):

Think of postfix increment `i++` as having a second (missing) parameter (i.e. `i++x`).  So postfix increment signature has a righthand parameter while the prefix increment does not.