# Why isn't the overloaded operator function being found?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I overloaded the increment operator in a C++ project, but when I try and invoke it the overload function is not found.

```
TListIterator< T > & operator ++( void )
{
    TListElement< T > *pNext = pCurrent->getNext();

    if( pCurrent && pNext )
        this->pCurrent = pNext;

    return *this;
}
```

I try and invoke like so:

```
(*it)++;
```

The overload method is a part of the 'TListIterator' class, and it is a pointer to a TListIterator.

The error I am receiving is:

```
Error   C2676   binary '++': 'TListIterator<T>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Edit To explain to the person marking my question as a duplicate to the one you linked me to:

The other post is directly asking how you differentiate between post-increment and pre-increment overloads, where as I did not know the reason my call did not work was due to overloading the wrong operator making my question entirely different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ increment operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777375/c-increment-operator)

Comment: Would `operator ++` need to be one thing, like `operator++` ?

Comment: No space doesn't count, although when I was pulling my hair out I did try removing the space to no avail. i'll look in to that tkausl

Comment: Distinguish pre-increment and post-increment.

Comment: Oh wow Nicky C you are my saviour; for post-increment it needs a dummy 'int' in order to work, otherwise I would call it ++(*it); Do you want to post your comment as an answer for me to mark correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you overload the increment operator, there are only two methods. So try to define your function as follows:

```
TListIterator< T > & operator ++()
```

or

```
TListIterator< T > & operator ++(int)
```

in which the first for prefix and the second for suffix.

Comment: Thanks, I just got the answer from Nicky C in the comments just before you posted this, but thank you to you also; i have been pulling my hair out over this.